# Per pixel collision detection in Javascript/Jquery/Gamequery

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection

I am trying to program a web game in Jquery with the GameQuery plugin, problem is the GameQuery plugin has no support for per pixel collision detection only collision detection with bounding boxes. Is it possible to implement per pixel collision detection in javascript/Jquery?

I have a world map with countries and a player which is moved using the arrow keys, I want to be able to tell which country the player is in at any time and the countries are irregular shapes.

Comment: How are the irregularly-shaped objects built? Are they each one big image? ... or are they made up from coloured DOM elements?

Comment: We plan on having each country as a seperate element, it is drawn onto the screen as a png, but if it would be easier as a single big image the plans can be changed to accomodate that. We thought of an idea of mapping each individual pixel to a country and checking the position the player against the pixel map to get the country, would that be efficient?

Comment: It may not be efficient but it seems the only way to do it. I may be able to help more if I can see an example of the type of images you're using (i.e. solid-color or terrain-dependent color) -- it might be possible to use canvas' `getImageData` to determine whether a specific pixel is within the country, as long as the country object is sufficiently differentiated to the rest of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Or attack it from a different angle...so to speak...

Vectors may be your key, cool stuff happening at http://www.raphaeljs.com

maybe some sort of combo/integration could work?

Answer (score 1):

alright here is kind of a solution:

assign each country a different color in you map (do not assign special colors to borders, borders should be colored in either color of the countries).

load that image into a canvas

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'worldmap.png';
var map = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
map.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

after that you can display your normal map above that map (it is only a reference, and can be hidden under other stuff - use divs and z-index for that).

to determine in which country the player is just get the pixel-data at his position

```
data = map.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
key = data.join("-"); // something like "255-0-0-255" for red
country = countries[key];
```

it should be an rgba-array, you may then look up what country is assigned to that color.
so you will have to keep an array with the imploded rgba-values as key and the country names as value.

```
countries = {
"255-0-0-255"   : "Russia",
"255-0-255-255" : "China",
...
};
```

this does only work in browsers that have the canvas object. so if you are doing this on iphone or android you are lucky!

Answer (score 0):

The images are just pngs with solid colours for the country and transparency for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

You have, however, a not very complicated alternative: use polygon-based collision.

Use an image to present the countries to the user, but use a polygon internally.

You may find a very complete explanation about how to implement this on [this forum entry](http://love2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1502) (you may have to scroll down a bit, until you see the images). The guy asking the question there wanted to do more or less the same as you want todo (mouse position instead of character position).

Regards!